# What indexes should I use with MySQL for a m:n-relationship?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two tables, a and b, and want to create a m:n-relationship between the columns.
Naturally, I create a third table ab with the columns a_id and b_id.

Since all pairs should be unique, I create a primary index over both fields and one btree-index for each field.
Now I have 3 indexes over a table with just 2 fields and think this is overkill.
Are indexes for both columns actually needed or does MySQL handle cases like this in a special way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary index over (a_id, b_id) will also cover searches on just a_id, so it is unnecessary to index a_id separately.

Comment: @tstenner: Besides my vast years of experience? :-) See: [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: No offense, but I know people with vast years of experience who use their knowledge from 1999 in technical decisions, even though the basis for their arguments isn't valid anymore. But thanks for the link, it explains everything I need.

Comment: @tstenner: No offense taken. I've worked with some of those same people.

Comment: You're right.  I just deleted the comment.  I was thinking about a different kind of association.